# Ожидание загрузки изображения

Tags: javascript, vue.js

С backend приезжает текст в формате md (markdown). Движки, которые умеют в md, обычно преобразуют его в html. Внутри md есть картинки и немного стилей. Вопрос, как мне долждаться, пока картинки загрузятся?

Сейчас я вставляю полученный из md text в свойство `v-html`. Но как туда засунуть скрипт, я не знаю.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Существует [компонент](https://github.com/alexjoverm/v-runtime-template/), который позволяет runtime рендерить компоненты. В таком случае, вы можете на лету встроить переменные, которые будут мониториться в `data`, vuejs и у вас появится реактивность. Ровно таким же образом, внутри `v-html`, у вас будут доступны те скрипты, которые есть снаружи `v-html`, т.е. в разделе `methods`.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/470829)

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov ок. Во многом этот ответ для меня. Он даже сформулирован так, что его будет сложно найти кому-то ещё. Позже, я его отредактирую. Я иногда причёсываю свои вопросы.